# Converting an admin UI design into Ember components

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering if their is a tutorial on how to convert an admin UI into Ember components? What are the best practices? For example, the following UI framework: http://egemem.com/theme/kode/v1.1/blank.html

Has a main navigation, two sidebar menus, a content body and a footer. What would the best approach be to converting this into components? My initial thoughts, with very little Ember experience and based on the scattering of documents I've been able to find, I get the sense that creating unique components for everything would be the best approach. By everything I mean, everything that is unique. For example, if we take the navigation bar, there would be a parent component for the navigation as a whole and then child components for the sidebar collapse/expand buttons, the search, the drop down menus, notification indicator, etc. There would also be additional parent components for the right hand sidebar, left hand sidebar, and footer.

Looking at one of the sidebars, for example the left one, could that be one component or would child components be required here as well?

The right hand sidebar is more complex with tabs. In this example, would it make sense to break this sidebar into child components for the 3 different tabs? Would you want to go as far as a unique component for different elements of the tabs themselves. For example, each notification type would be a component?

Thank you in advance for your assistance send I look forward to understanding how best to handle this type of scenario.

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea makes sense. It is a good practice to create components (or handlebars) for everything that repeats several times. I would not create different components for different tabs if they are not re-used.

Do not forget to not re-invent wheel. There are a lot of available components, take a look at [Ember Observer](http://emberobserver.com) or other similar resources.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if the nav bar will always be the same (consistent) on every view, then do I need to go as far as breaking it down into sub components I.e components for search and each drop down? Cheers

Comment: I would create a component for sidebar, sidebar item with drop down and probably search. Although re-usability should be one of the top priorities, it makes sense to create component that encapsulate functionality even without reusing.

Answer (score 0):

Components are great but some the things you mentioned, like sidebars, might make more sense as nested routes, depending on what's in the sidebars.

Rock 'n Roll with Ember is a fantastic book that takes you all the way through the process of building an Ember application. It's the book I always recommend to people just getting started with the framework. http://balinterdi.com/rock-and-roll-with-emberjs/